# Debugging a C executable with a C++-CLI Library compiled with /clr

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to debug an application mostly written in C.  Normally, I can attach the debugger just fine, but I am running in to some problems when I link in a library written in C++ / CLI.

If I compile the library with the `/clr` flag (which I will eventually have to do for this as of yet unwritten library) then I lose all ability to debug the entire C application, even the parts that have nothing to do with the library calls.  I get the empty circle with the yellow triangle and exclamation mark where a red break point circle ought to be.  Hovering over it gives me only a tool tip that says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation or compiler optimizations."

Then if I link with the exact same library compiled *without* the `/clr` flag, I am again able to debug my application.

I understand that visual studio will not likely be able to debug the library written in C++ / CLI, and that is OK.  I just want to keep the ability to debug the rest of the application and at least see the results of my calls to the external library.

Another complicating factor is that this project is not being built by visual studio.  It is compiled using an external make system that uses `cl`, so I can customize any commands that need to be issued to the compiler that way.

Does anyone know why I can't currently debug the libraries the way I want to?  Any advice for how I can?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to select the *kind* of debugger when you attach.  Note the "Attach to" label in the dialog.  Press the Select button and tick "Native" to get support for debugging native code.  The DLL also needs to be loaded before any of your breakpoints can hit.  If you are not sure whether or not that was done then look in the Debug > Windows > Modules debugger window to see loaded DLLs.  The breakpoint indicator turns from hollow to solid red as soon as the debugger saw the DLL load and armed the breakpoint.

Debugging C++/CLI is otherwise supported, you can tick both the "Managed" and "Native" checkboxes.  And set breakpoints in either kind of code.  The only thing not supported is single-stepping from managed to native code and back.  A mode-switch is required to activate the correct debugging engine, that requires code to hit a breakpoint.

And consider the Debug options in your native project, you can specify an EXE to start.  So that you can simply press F5 to start debugging and skip the attach hassle.

Answer (score 3):

It might also have to do with the **Debugger Type**!
(but that depends on your specific building configuration about which I do not know enough)

**If any of your projects is complied with Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) you should set the Debugger Type in your startup project to "Mixed", since the default setting "Auto" might fail!**

Imagine, you have two projects:

1) A non-CLR C++ project, which is your startup project that generates some .exe file.

2) A C++ project, that generates mylibrary.dll, which is compiled with Common Language Runtime Support, because it uses some managed code. The .exe from the first project calls mylibrary.dll.

If you start the first project with Debugger Type set to its default value "Auto", you'll be able to debug into the first project, but not into the second one. The debugger selector does not realize that you will be calling a CLR-library.

**So set Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Debugger Type to "Mixed"!**